# Install macOS Monterey on data or univeristy wifi

Tags: macos, wifi, monterey, data, restart

I had to recently reset macOS Monterey on my macbook, but it then asked to download and install the latest version. Currently I am at university, so I did not know if it was the best idea to either install the update using my phone's hotspot with data, or if I should use the university wifi (which I don't know if I necessarily trust completely).

If anyone could give me some insight, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust could mean a few different things, but the first that come to my mind can be easily alleviated:

- Trust it to not disconnect mid-upgrade: not a problem.
  The entire upgrade is downloaded before it starts. If the download is interrupted, it will continue from where it left off. Once downloaded, internet connectivity is no longer necessary.
- Trust it to not be intercepted: not a problem.
  Upgrades are code signed using Apple’s signature, which Gatekeeper will verify

  > **Some software updates are automatically verified**
  > When you download and install an update from Apple, Apple's digital signature is automatically verified before installation.

  https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202369

and you can still verify yourself: [How can I determine if a certain .app file is signed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82587/37797).

Therefore you should just use the University network as it will be faster.

Comment: Yeah @grg I meant trust as in anything getting intercepted or any malware getting injected during the installation. Do you know of any ways to verify the installation at the end, or should I just trust gatekeeper to have the authentic apple installation

Comment: @TheGeno See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82587/37797, you can run this on the ‘Install macOS Monterey’ app

Comment: Hi @grg, since the 'Install macOS Monterey' app is not yet installed (I'm currently at the recovery page), would I just verify it after I actually install Monterey, or is there a way I can do it from the recovery page itself?

Comment: @TheGeno As you’re in recovery, I’m not sure how you would check it manually. It’s still having its signature checked automatically by the recovery environment though.

Comment: Ok, I'll try installing it then. Do you know of any ways to verify the install afterwards by any chance @grg?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a lot of safeguards in place to make sure that internet recovery is secure. It's not publicly documented, but I'd imagine it's hard-coded to happen only over an encrypted connection that's not easily [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)'d. Additionally, if your macbook is a 2018 or later model, you're protected by [Secure Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198).

I'd go ahead and use the university wifi.