# Why does Messages close on launch?

Tags: macos, messages

I'm running MacOS 11.5.1, and whenever I launch messages it closes itself. I ran the "messages" file inside (`Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages`) and it printed out this error:

```
/.../Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages ; exit;
XXX@XXX ~ % /.../Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages ; exit;
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/../Frameworks in /.../Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path (Codesign main executable with Library Validation to allow @ paths)
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/Frameworks in /.../Applications/Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path (Codesign main executable with Library Validation to allow @ paths)
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /.../Applications/.Messages.app/Contents/MacOS/Messages being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path (Codesign main executable with Library Validation to allow @ paths)
```

After looking around online, it seemed that the error was with the code-signing of messages. But that couldn't be possible, because it's an apple-distributed pre-installed app... I still receive messages through notifications and I can reply inside those notifications, but the app won't launch anymore.

codesign says the "resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get different results using launch services to start the app `open -a messages`?

Comment: It appears to produce a longer output log, but it's just more of the same error and it won't launch.

Comment: Bummer. Sounds like your OS or security system got botched. Want me to answer how to do a reinstall or test in safe boot mode or check if the [app signing still is valid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82588/5472)?

Comment: I just checked the codesign and it says the "resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)"

Answer (score 0):

If this were an app you built, you could re-sign it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008449/xcodebuild-codesign-vvvv-saysresource-envelope-is-obsolete

Might be time to reinstall the OS unless you know why this one app was modified and have a backup to restore it. Definitely reinstall if other apps are failing code signatures.